# What are the valid options for a Gridview datasource?

Tags: .net, gridview

I know I can set a Gridview datasource to a dataset, or to a collection of objects. Are there other choices?

This seems like a very basic question, like I should be able to go to the Microsoft documentation, look up "gridview / properties / datasource", and it would say, "You can set this to ..." and a list of the valid datatypes. But I can't find any such thing. Can someone point me to a reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataSource has to be one of these interfaces:

- IListSource
- IEnumerable
- IDataSource

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.databoundcontrol.validatedatasource.aspx)